# UITabBarController + UITableView = Errors!

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to use a UINavigationController, UITabBarController, and UITableView together.

I started with a Navigation-based app, and at one point push a UIViewController (called `CarViewController`) onto the navigationController.  I want to use a TabBar within the `CarViewController`, so I dragged a UITabBarController into `CarViewController`'s .xib, declared a `IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController` in the .h file, synthesized it in the .m file, then in Interface Builder I connected `File's Owner -> tabBarController` to the tab bar controller and made File's Owner the tab bar's delegate.

This works just fine with tabs for other UIViews, but the problem I'm having is that I cannot get any tabs to work that have UITableViewControllers.  The debugger claims there's an error in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` but I have an NSLog in there that's not even being run.

Here's what the debugger output is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x592f1d0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0238e919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024dc5de objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0239042b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x02300116 ___forwarding___ + 966
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x022ffcd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
 5   UIKit                               0x001c9a24 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1834
 6   UIKit                               0x001cb9c1 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:] + 108
 7   UIKit                               0x001cb24d -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 60
 8   UIKit                               0x0008e596 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateContentSize] + 333
 9   UIKit                               0x0007db7e -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 123
 10  UIKit                               0x0008a1d2 -[UITableView reloadData] + 773
 11  UIKit                               0x000873f4 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 42
 12  QuartzCore                          0x03a630d5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
 13  QuartzCore                          0x03a62e05 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
 14  QuartzCore                          0x03a6264c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 302
 15  QuartzCore                          0x03a622b0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
 16  QuartzCore                          0x03a69f5b _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x0236fd1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
 18  CoreFoundation                      0x02304987 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
 19  CoreFoundation                      0x022cdc17 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
 20  CoreFoundation                      0x022cd280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 21  CoreFoundation                      0x022cd1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 22  GraphicsServices                    0x025d92c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
 23  GraphicsServices                    0x025d938d GSEventRun + 115
 24  UIKit                               0x00022b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
 25  Test Application                    0x000029b4 main + 102
 26  Test Application                    0x00002945 start + 53
 27  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
 )
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

Just for reference, here is the applicable code from the UITableViewController's implementation:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"Hi, this is the function that should be firing but is not!");
    return 5;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test Item";
    return cell;
}
```

At this point I have a blank project and I'm just trying to mock up the interface, so other than having this mis-structured there's nothing else going on in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be calling the UITableViewDelegate methods on a `UIViewController`.  Re-check the connections in IB - occasionally even the best mis-wire things...

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason, your program is trying to call tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: on an instance of UIViewController, and not UITableViewController :

[**UIViewController** tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x592f1d0'

I don't know why but that should be a good starting point for your investigations...

Answer (score 0):

Check your TabBarController in IB. You have to change the type of view controller to table view controller or you will get this trace.(In the Tab Bar Controller Attribute).